# Move floated CSS speech bubble to new line

Tags: css

I adapted this CSS from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/mek5Z/):

```
.chat {
    width: 400px;
}
.bubble {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content:"\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    width: 20px;
}
.me {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
}
.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, .4);
    left: -9px;
}
.you {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
}
.you::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, .4);
    right: -9px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bubble me">Hello there!</div>
<div class="bubble you">Hi. I'm an expandeable chat box with box shadow. How are you? I expand      horizontally and vertically, as you can see here.</div>
<div class="bubble me">Awesome.1</div>
<div class="bubble you">Awesome.2</div>
<div class="bubble me">Awesome.3</div>
<div class="bubble you">Awesome.4</div>
```

This really looks good except for 1 problem.

The problem is the bubble message will be arranged horizontally if we don't fix the div width.

**Current result:**

[image: Current]

**Desired result:**

[image: Desired]

Comment: Can't see the issue you describe. Can you post a fiddle with the actual problem?

Comment: I added <div> section and if you test this, you will see like... Awesome.1 ~ 4 will be positioned in one line.

Comment: not clear on what you want, are you saying you'd like to make the text in the bubble wrap at specific points? like injecting a `<br />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floated elements will stick together on the same line; this is prevented with the CSS `clear` property.

In your case you just need to:

- Set `clear: both` on `.me` and `.you`.

This has the added benefit of keeping "me" and "you" replies on a different line when they contain only a small amount of text.

[Read more about the CSS clear property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

CSS

```
.me {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
}
.you {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Runnable example:

```css
.chat {
    width: 400px;
}
.bubble {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content:"\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
    width: 20px;
}
.me {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
}
.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, .4);
    left: -9px;
}
.you {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
}
.you::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, .4);
    right: -9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
    <div class="bubble me">Hello there!</div>
    <div class="bubble you">Hi. I'm an expandeable chat box with box shadow. How are you? I expand horizontally and vertically, as you can see here.</div>
    <div class="bubble me">Awesome.</div>
    <div class="bubble me">Awesome.</div>
    <div class="bubble me">Awesome.</div>
    <div class="bubble you">Awesome.</div>
    <div class="bubble me">Awesome.</div>

</div>
```